# querySelector in Typescript Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

So I have a ts Error, while using Vue Composition API

```
 let myElement = document.querySelectorAll('my-element')
```

the error I get in TS, while accesing it like this: Property '_props' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts

```
myElement._props.value
```

what I have tried:

```
let myElement = document.querySelector('my-element') as HTMLElement
```

Comment: What are you expecting `_props` to be? Are you trying to get a Vue component like this?

Answer (score -1):

Before the page is rendered, it wants to get the information while the element has not yet been created.
According to the life cycle of vue3 in the link below, you will understand this issue
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html
You should receive the relevant information after the page is rendered